# How to create a custom shaped CardView android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Hello, I'm semi new to android development and I want to create 2 card views that are custom shapes (as seen above) I was wondering if this is possible and how I would go about doing it. Thanks

Comment: Use drawable file to achieve that shapes.

Comment: thanks, ill look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using vectors made in Illustrator and importing them into Android Studio as PNGs. Then I set the PNGs as the background of LinearLayouts.